# Force non www in browsers and UIWebView

Tags: ios, firefox, uiwebview

I have a problem with `UIWebView` but this also applies to all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Whenever I enter manually url:

https://server.com

All of those browsers and `UIWebView` add `www`, no matter what I do. I tried to redirect everything from `www` to non `www` but it only works when exception is added.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because cert is valid for non www only.

Comment: OK Here are some more things I found. Let's assume its https://example.com I want. If I create rewrite condition in htacces let's say https://example.com/panel that goes to index.php?id=panel, it works fine. No browser adds www into it. But If I create /panel folder and try to access it, then every browser forces www in URL and I can't solve this.